# Eloquent relationship returning error Trying to get property of non-object in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I have gone through similar questions but haven't been able to see where or what I'm doing wrong.

So I've set up a relationship between employees and task like this

Task model

```
class Task extends Model
{
    public function employee()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class, 'employee_id');
    }
}
```

Empoyee model

```
public function tasks()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
}
```

My tasks table structure uses the employee_id as the foreign key

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('employee_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('employee_id')->references('id')->on('employees')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->string('priority');
        $table->date('begin');
        $table->date('end');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

In my view, I'm trying to return the list of task along with the employee's first but i'm getting the error "Trying to get property of non-object"

```
@foreach ($allTask as $task)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $task->priority }}</td>
        <td>{{ $task->title }}</td>
        <td>{{ ucfirst($task->employee->firstname) }} {{" "}} {{ ucfirst($task->employee->lastname) }}</td>
        <td>{{ $task->end }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

When i dump and die the data from my controller with this,

```
public function index()
{
    $allTask = Task::with('employee')->limit(5)->get();

    /*return view('home', compact('allTask'));*/

    dd($allTask);
}
```

I'm able to see this

```
`#original: array:9 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "employee_id" => 2
    "title" => "Roaster"
    "description" => "Submission of work roaster has commenced and you are expected to submit before the due date"
    "priority" => "high"
    "begin" => "2017-06-26"
    "end" => "2017-06-30"
    "created_at" => "2017-06-26 22:32:39"
    "updated_at" => "2017-06-26 22:32:39"
  ]`
```

Where am I getting it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably one of your returned  `tasks` does not have all the fields you are trying to show,
change your template as follow :

```
@foreach ($allTask as $task)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ isset($task->priority) ? $task->priority : 'no priority !'  }}</td>
        <td>{{  isset($task->title) ? $task->title : 'no title!'  }}</td>
        <td>{{  isset($task->employee->firstname) ?  ucfirst($task->employee->firstname) : 'no first name!' }} {{" "}} {{ 
 isset($task->employee->lastname) ? ucfirst($task->employee->lastname) : 'no last name!' }}</td>
        <td>{{  isset($task->end) ? $task->end : 'no end!'  }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

**Update:**

You are printing the `employee` in a wrong way!

we can have two ways to accomplish this:

1-

```
$allTask = Task::with('employee')->limit(5)->get();

isset($task->employee[0]) ?  ucfirst($task->employee[0]->firstname) : 'empty'
```

2-

```
$allTask = Task::with(['employee' => function($q){
   $q->first();
}])->limit(5)->get();

isset($task->employee) ?  ucfirst($task->employee->firstname) : 'empty'
```

Comment: I have just one task added for test purpose and it has all fields. Doing it your will always make the first & lastname fields as 'no first/last name'

Comment: @Mena ok i get it!  Did you create any `empolyee` for this task ?  I think the problem is you have no employee OR more than one employee for this `task`, I will update the answer

Comment: I have added more employees and created task for them successfully but that did not fix it.

Comment: @Mena  when you use this : `Task::with('employee')->limit(5)->get();`,  the relation is retuning as array and you should use it like :  `$task->employee[0]->firstname` or   `$task->employee[1]->firstname` ....

Comment: My code is working now. The only thing i did differently, was delete the very first task i created then added 2 more and kept my code in it's original state and it worked well. Strange i think